# how to import the eth-lightwallet package to the react-native project?

Tags: android, react-native, ethereum, web3js

First, I created a project: `react-native init project`, and
when I try to `import * as lightwallet from 'eth-lightwallet'` in my react-native project, I get an error [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46r1j.png.)

Found a solution [at github](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/issues/5), but this did not solve the problem for me.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "androidWallet",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "asn1": "^0.2.3",
    "buffer": "^5.2.0",
    "eth-lightwallet": "^3.0.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.1.0",
    "node-libs-react-native": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.2",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.1.8",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web3": "^0.20.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please paste the error message as text in your question. See: [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `eth-lightwallet` depends on node core modules that isn't supported by React Native out of the box. The current workaround involves using 
[rn-nodeify](https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify) in order to provide shims for React Native to use instead. See [this issue for react native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14796) and see [this open issue from eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/issues/139).